# get file's last modified date stamp in Unix

Tags: file, unix, unix-timestamp, last-modified

I need to find the file last modified date stamp in Unix.

Please help me me in finding the solution.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ls -lct
```

to show and sort by last modification time.

For a single file you can use `stat`, for the human readable format

```
stat --format=%y file
```

or

```
stat --format=%Y file
```

for seconds since Epoch.

Comment: HI Diego,
Thanks for the reply, 
I tried the above commands, they are working in linux env,  But not working in Unix env

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: This doesn't work. `stat --format=%y file` prints `2023-08-02 10:41:46.159878046 +0200`, which is clearly not a Unix timestamp. `ls -lct` is even worse, it prints `Aug  2 10:41`. I need the Unix timestamp, which in this case would be `1622894933374`.